# What's sense has Discriminated unions does not infer (and create) the type?

Tags: f#

I have 2 types of Animal:

```
type Person(name) =
    member this.Name: string = name
    
type Cat(age) =
    member this.Age: int = age
```

The I "join" the types:

```
type Animal =
| Person of Person
| Cat of Cat
| Dog
```

When I try to create a Person instance:

```
let person = new Person("Alex")
```

I get the error:

> Union case Animal.Person: Person -> Animal
>
> The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Person'

**Question:**

**Person** is a **class** with a constructor,

The type **Animal.Person** should be an **instance of Person**. So, what's the problem?

**Edit:**
Visual Studio for Windows doesn't show errors, but if you add more source, you get the error "'Person' does not match type 'Animal'":

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let person = new Person("Alex")

    person
    |> KnowAnimal
    |> printfn "%O"
```

Comment: So what's your question. The reason it doesn't work is the same reason why it didn't work in your previous question. And the same solutions apply. Please clarify.

Comment: @Gustavo "How" in my previous question and now "why". Person is a class with a constructor, the type Animal.Person should be an instance of Person. So, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you showed the correct code? I don't get any error message when I run your code - it works just fine.

Comment: `let person: Animal = Person(new Person("Alex"))`

Comment: @JeffMercado But I'm "joining" different types. Why must I specify the type is part of the Animal enumeration? I explicity specify Animal.Person has type Person.

Comment: Right, it _has_ type Person, not _is_. The same difference for this: `type Value = Number of int | String of string`, `Number` isn't an int, it has an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type Animal.Person should be an instance of Person. So, what's the problem?

First of all `Animal.Person` is not a type, `Person` is a type and `Animal` is a type. `Animal.Person` is a case of the `Animal` type that takes a `Person` as a parameter. That is, it serves as a function of type `Person -> Animal`, so it takes a value of type `Person` and returns a value of type `Animal`. There is no sub-type relationship between these two types.

So `person` is a value of type `Person` and `Person person` is a value of type `Animal` because `Person` takes a `Person` and returns an `Animal`.